# How compatible are VMWare and VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

At my workplace, everyone uses VMware Player (and some people have licenses for Workstation). We frequently share VMs to save time on development setup. However, I would really like to take advantage of the Snapshot feature in VirtualBox since I am unable to acquire a license for Workstation.

I have read that VirtualBox has no issues reading VMWare VMs (including VMs with snapshots). However, I'm worried about how compatible things are the other way.

In VirtualBox, I open up a VM created in VMware and create multiple snapshots. Can the resulting files be opened in VMware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used VMWare VMDK files under VirtualBox with great success, but not for the past 18 months or so, during which VB has had multiple releases. I would be surprised if it did not work. However, VMWare would not be able to handle VB snapshots--you'd have to "accept" (I don't remember the actual word) all the changes recorded in the snapshots to make a single VMDK file for your VMWare-using co-workers to use the file.

Answer (score 1):

They can coexist but they don't really share VM container files very well.  Also, VirtualBox supports ACPI 2.0 guests, but VMware Workstation 7.1.4 still does not (if that matters).